# When and why did Girondins split from Jacobins

Tags: french-revolution

So I'm reading through Schama's *Citizens* and am thoroughly confused. I've gathered that at the beginning there were [Feuillants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feuillant_(political_group)) and [Jacobins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobin), of whom the majority were followers of [Brissot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacques_Pierre_Brissot), the [Girondins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Girondins).

Then at some point the Jacobins center around [Robespierre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximilien_Robespierre) and the Girondins are separate?

I know this isn't right.  What's the chronology here and what am I not understanding?

Comment: The best source to understand anything about the French Revolution is Mike Duncan's [Revolutions podcast](http://www.revolutionspodcast.com/2014/11/316-the-society-of-1789.html) - I've linked to an episode that is earlier than the Girondins ,but you'll enjoy the progres.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Girondins presumably covers it